# Is it possible to count number of XML nodes in a node-set with JSTL XML tags in jsp?

Tags: xml, jsp, jstl, xmlnode

I'm trying to count the number of book nodes from the xml below:

```
<books>
    <book>Title1</book>
    <book>Title2</book>
    <book>Title3</book>
    <book>Title4</book>
    <book>Title5</book>
</books>
```

I tried using XPath's count function, inside the JSP page, but it gives 0 instead of 5 - (the number of book nodes).

could you please provide me the way to get the number of book nodes using jstl xml tags in jsp.

Thanks,

Venu

Answer (score -1):

What have you tried? Doing an xsl transform like this seems to work:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="count(//book)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Returns `5` for your example, at least on [w3schools xsl playground](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog).

Comment: Thanks Anders for your answer but I need the count of the number book nodes in jsp page using jstl.

Comment: Have you tried the x:transform tag? 

http://www.roseindia.net/jstl/transform-xml-jstl-tag.shtml

Comment: I haven't tried x:transform tag. is it possible to get the number of nodes in jsp without using x:transform tag?